# Unique values from multipel column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
distinct_values = df.col_name.unique().compute()
```

But what if I don't know the names of columns.

Comment: you want unique values from all columns or subset of columns?

Comment: from all columns

Comment: It is showing the following error                                                                                  raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: Or what if i want unique values from only one column but i dont know the column name

Comment: please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am not sure, as I understand it, `np.array(merged.drop_duplicates())` or 
```arr = []

for col in merged.columns:
    arr.extend(merged[col].unique())```

Comment: The sample data is    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SXMHPXjf0LpeHCe6p4jrdfSsTWGLzPic      And expected output is a dictionary : {"any_column_name" : [ unique words]}

Comment: {'colA': df['colA'].unique().tolist()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"colA":['a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e'], "colB":[1,2,1,2,1]})

unique_dict = {}

# df.columns will give you list of columns in dataframe
for col in df.columns:
    unique_dict[col] = list(df[col].unique())
```

Output:

```
{'colA': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], 'colB': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i only want unique values from only one column

Comment: Then you should know the column name and you can access above dictionary from keys.  eg. `unique_dict["colA"]`

Comment: unique_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    distinct_values = df.[col].unique().compute()   Why it is not working??

Comment: You have extra `.` after df in `df.[col].unique()`. It should be `df[col].unique()` and I am not sure what `compute` method does

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 5]})
>>> d = dict()
>>> d['any_column_name'] = pd.unique(df.values.ravel('K'))
>>> d
{'any_column_name': array([1, 2, 3, 5])}
```

or for just one feature,

```py
>>> d = dict()
>>> d['a'] = df['a'].unique()
>>> d
{'a': array([1, 2, 3])}
```

or individually for all,

```py
>>> d = dict()
>>> for col in df.columns:
...     d[col] = df[col].unique()
...
>>> d
{'a': array([1, 2, 3]), 'b': array([2, 3, 5])}
```